# Spring with angularJs

Tags: java, angularjs, spring

i am looking at the spring website for a angularJs- spring application.

https://spring.io/blog/2015/01/12/spring-and-angular-js-a-secure-single-page-application

i followed every instruction in the blog and could run the application successfully. but the problem is since its a secure application, my chrome browser is not allowing me enter in as it is asking for username and password, but the blog says it should work fine.

but i keep getting the login page

[image]

can any spring or angular gurus please let me know how to get through authentication. i posted a question on the blog, but no reply as of now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the section **Running the Application** it is stated that

> When you load the home page you should get a browser dialog asking for username and password (the username is “user” and the password is printed in the console logs on startup)

Comment: Should be something like: `default password: xx...x`.